# Task.Delay for more than int.MaxValue milliseconds

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

The maximum duration a `Task.Delay` can be told to delay is `int.MaxValue` milliseconds. What is the cleanest way to create a `Task` which will delay beyond that time?

```
// Fine.
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(int.MaxValue));

// ArgumentOutOfRangeException
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(int.MaxValue + 1L));
```

Comment: I can't fathom a circumstance in which you'd want to delay something for ... (checks calculator) ... 24.86 days.

Comment: 25 days is a long time to wait. If you want to wait forever you can use `Task.Delay(-1)`

Comment: @DanielMann I'm writing a cache which removes entries after a given period. While it's unlikely anyone will want to cache something that long, I don't want it to be a limiting factor.

Comment: `Task.Delay` doesn't seem appropriate for that scenario.

Comment: Do you have any alternative approaches? My code (simplified) boils down to: `AddEntry(key, value); Task.Delay(12345).ContinueWith(/* Remove entry. */);`

Comment: @PhilK do you know anyone else that has ever had the though of doing this? Why don't you just had an expiration date to the cache entry and have the cache periodically remove expired entries?

Comment: @PauloMorgado: Just hit this case. The cache size is 1 and the expected TTL of the cache entry is in years. Guess the thread's going to wake up once every 25 days.

Comment: it sucks that the API imposes some hidden limit on the maximum timespan duration you can use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't achieve that using a single `Task.Delay` since it internally uses a `System.Threading.Timer` that only accepts an int.

However you can do that using multiple waits one after the other. Here's the cleanest way:

```
static async Task Delay(long delay)
{
    while (delay > 0)
    {
        var currentDelay = delay > int.MaxValue ? int.MaxValue : (int) delay;
        await Task.Delay(currentDelay);
        delay -= currentDelay;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can delay multiple times. For example:

```
static async Task LongDelay(long milliseconds)
{
    if (milliseconds < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }

    if (milliseconds == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    int iterations = (milliseconds - 1) / int.MaxValue;

    while (iterations-- > 0)
    {
        await Task.Delay(int.MaxValue);
        milliseconds -= int.MaxValue;
    }

    await Task.Delay(milliseconds);
}
```

That said, `int.MaxValue` milliseconds is a *really* long time, almost 25 days! IMHO a much more important question is, is the `Task.Delay()` method really the best solution for your scenario? Knowing more about why you are trying to wait for such a long period of time might help others offer you a better solution to the *actual* problem, instead of addressing this very specific need.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily write a method to break it down into smaller delays:

```
private static readonly TimeSpan FullDelay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(int.MaxValue);

private static async Task LongDelay(TimeSpan delay)
{
    long fullDelays = delay.Ticks / FullDelay.Ticks;
    TimeSpan remaining = delay;
    for(int i = 0; i < fullDelays; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(FullDelay);
        remaining -= FullDelay;
    }

    await Task.Delay(remaining); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you care about precision, you should be using `Stopwatch` rather than deviding `delay` by `Int16.MaxValue` chunks. This is how the below code is different from other answers:

```
    private static async Task LongDelay(TimeSpan delay)
    {
        var st = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        st.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            var remaining = (delay - st.Elapsed).TotalMilliseconds;
            if (remaining <= 0)
                break;
            if (remaining > Int16.MaxValue)
                remaining = Int16.MaxValue;
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(remaining));
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: According to @CoryNelson's comment, `Stopwatch` is not good enough for long laps. If so, it's possible to simply use `DateTime.UtcNow`:

```
    private static async Task LongDelay(TimeSpan delay)
    {
        var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
        while (true)
        {
            var remaining = (delay - (DateTime.UtcNow - start)).TotalMilliseconds;
            if (remaining <= 0)
                break;
            if (remaining > Int16.MaxValue)
                remaining = Int16.MaxValue;
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(remaining));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Due to not being affected by the system date/time (and adjustments thereof), Stopwatch will present some amount of skew as the inaccuracies of the system's clock build up. It is not intended for measuring long periods of time.

Comment: @CoryNelson, interesting, I didn't know about such shortcomings of `Stopwatch`. Could you point me at some sources confirming this? Anyhow, using `DateTime.UtcNow` should be reliable enough I believe, I updated the code.

Comment: See the [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408.aspx) docs, not easy to link to but search for "accumulated error". It is what Stopwatch uses behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

As of .NET 6, the maximum valid `TimeSpan delay` value of the [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) method is now 4,294,967,294 milliseconds (`0xFFFFFFFE`, or `UInt32.MaxValue - 1`), which is approximately 49 days and 17 hours. It is the same limit with the `dueTime`/`period` arguments of the [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer) constructor, on which the `Task.Delay` is based internally.

Related GitHub issue: [`Task.Delay` actual accepted delay is twice the documented value](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/68818)

Answer (score 1):

Improved on @i3arnon version, which use multiple waits (delays) one after the other.:

- Added support for optional cancellation token.
- Added support for TimeSpan argument.
- The method reproduces the same behavior as the original Task.Delay.
- Parameter names are more consistent with the original method.
- Added usage remark.

Note: Using the scheduler would be a good alternative to implement long delays.

```csharp
/// <summary>Allow to delay Task for 292,471,209 years.</summary>
/// <remarks>Usage makes sense if the process won't be recycled before the delay expires.</remarks>
public static async Task LongDelay(
  TimeSpan delay,
  CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)
) => await LongDelay((long)delay.TotalMilliseconds, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

/// <summary>Allow to delay Task for 292,471,209 years.</summary>
/// <remarks>Usage makes sense if the process won't be recycled before the delay expires.</remarks>
public static async Task LongDelay(
  long millisecondsDelay,
  CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)
) {
  // Use 'do' to run Task.Delay at least once to reproduce the same behavior.
  do {
    var delay = (int)Math.Min(int.MaxValue, millisecondsDelay);
    await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    millisecondsDelay -= delay;
  } while (millisecondsDelay > 0);
}
```

LongDelay example with CancellationToken:

```csharp
// Create a token that auto-cancels after 10 seconds.
var source = new CancellationTokenSource(10000);

// Delay for 20 seconds.
try { LongDelay(20000, source.Token).Wait(); }
catch (TaskCanceledException) { } // Cancel silently.
catch (Exception) { throw; }
```

Edit: Applied suggestion by @TheodorZoulias

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Every overload will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception if you pass a value that would resolve to a greater number of milliseconds than Int32.MaxValue. This is true even for the `TimeSpan` overload ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139096(v=vs.110).aspx)).

The best you could do is await twice:

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(int.MaxValue));
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20));
```

Comment: That also throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.